# "Insert key" text effect with Javascript

Tags: javascript, effect

I'm trying to replicate the "insert key" effect on some words with javascript but I'm nowhere near the result I hope. Basically I have 4-5 words that I want to display, one after another and I would like to use a "insert key" effect to hide/display the words sequentially.

Something like that: http://www.introwebsite.com/index2.asp (yes, I know it's in flash). Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By insert key, i assume you mean letters flash across for new words. I used something similar in a project which looked pretty cool - demo: http://sandbox.unwrongest.com/jquery.airport/

Or something SIMILAR (i stress similar) to this:

```
              var lis = $('#pieceOfText').hide();
              var i = 0;
              (function displayImages() {
                 lis.eq(i++).fadeIn(100, displayImages);
              })();
```

So you could grab each letter from a piece of text and fade them in one by one :)

Comment: That's kind of what I'm looking for! And yes, it looks cool but... any clue on how to stop the letters from shaking? It seems kind disturbating. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: *disturbing shaking? I think thats the effect, like they're scrolling through as they are getting inserted, like an Airport departures board

Comment: Yes, I get it. I was just wondering if it was possible to do that just by "overlaying" the words and not moving them while inserting.